# OPENQUERY SQL Server MYSQL UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-server, openquery

I have to work on a linked server. My goal: Update an entire table in mysql server(version:8.0.21) via OPENQUERY in SQL Server(version 13.0.1742.0). I tried this but it generates an error `Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read` and this one `The rowset was using optimistic concurrency and the value of a column has been changed after the containing row was last fetched or resynchronized`.

```
update linkedTable
set 
    linkedTable.id_parent=unlinkedTable.IdCat1,
    linkedTable.code=unlinkedTable.CodeFamilleFAT,
    linkedTable.niveau=unlinkedTable.NiveauCategorieFAT,
    linkedTable.langue=unlinkedTable.CodeLangueFAT,
    linkedTable.nom=unlinkedTable.LibelleCommercialFAT,
    linkedTable.descriptionA=unlinkedTable.DescriptifCom1FAT,
    linkedTable.vignette=null,
    linkedTable.id_categorie=unlinkedTable.id
from openquery(NAMELINKEDSERVER, 'select id_categorie, id_parent, code, niveau, langue, nom, description as descriptionA, vignette from DatabaseMySQL.Table') as linkedTable
inner join DatabaseSQLserver.dbo.Table as unlinkedTable on unlinkedTable.Id = linkedTable.id_categorie
```

Then I tried this:

```
update linkedTable
set 
    linkedTable.id_parent=unlinkedTable.IdCat1,
    linkedTable.code=unlinkedTable.CodeFamilleFAT,
    linkedTable.niveau=unlinkedTable.NiveauCategorieFAT,
    linkedTable.langue=unlinkedTable.CodeLangueFAT,
    linkedTable.nom=unlinkedTable.LibelleCommercialFAT,
    linkedTable.descriptionA=unlinkedTable.DescriptifCom1FAT,
    linkedTable.vignette=null,
    linkedTable.id_categorie=unlinkedTable.id
from openquery(NAMELINKEDSERVER, 'select id_categorie, id_parent, code, niveau, langue, nom, description as descriptionA, vignette from DatabaseMySQL.Table') as linkedTable
inner join DatabaseSQLserver.dbo.Table as unlinkedTable on unlinkedTable.Id = linkedTable.id_categorie
where linkedTable.id_categorie = 1
```

This work but only one row is updated. So I wrote a stored procedure to update each line but it took too much time.

Can someone explain why my first query didn't work (question1) and how I can reduce the time of my stored procedure (question2)?

I use while loop (count the number of id and update each id).

Thank you in advance.

Kind Regards.

Comment: "it generates an error" is significantly less informative than "it generates the following error: <your error message>". (And while you are at it, it can also help to mention the indexes on your mysql table, and maybe your server versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem by checking some option on ODBC Driver in MySQL and reading some forum. I check this box.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epVRl.png)

This option allows to avoid the errors quoted previously. With this option, i can update multiple values without error on join or other request. Thank you Solarflare and "Another guy" (i lost the name) for correcting me (EDIT A POST). Have nice day both.